# Problems while trying log in to website with perl

Tags: perl, mechanize

I am new to Perl and trying to access a website. I have tried this code I found on the internet:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use LWP;

my $username = 'user'; 
my $password = 'pass';

chomp($username);
chomp($pass);

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$mech->get('http://my_url.com');
$mech->form_name('theform');
$mech->field ('username' => $username);
$mech->field ('password' => $password);
$mech->click('Sign in');

print $mech->content();
```

The button is:

```
<input type="submit" name="sgnBt" title="Sign in" value="Sign in" id="sgnBt" class="btn btn-prim sd-sgnBtn">
```

The output is:

```
Error : No clickable input with name Sign in ...
```

Replacing the line $mech -> click('Sign in'); with `$mech -> submit();`  gives me the registration page, which is not the page I got after clicking the *Sign in* button.

I have also tried:

```
$mech->click_button(name => 'Sign in');
$mech->click_button(name => 'sgnBt');
$mech->click_button(value => 'Sign in');
```

But they all give the same error. Please advice, run out of thoughts. I have tried a lot of things.

Comment: If its the only button on the form, then just `$mech->click()` should work, otherwise, `$mech->click('sgnBt')` should work. You could `print Data::Dumper::Dumper $mech->current_form()` to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [$mech->submit_form()](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.60/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#%24mech-%3Esubmit_form%28_..._%29) instead of `$mech->click_button()`:

```
my $fields = {
    username => $username,
    password => $pass
};
my $response = $mech->submit_form( with_fields => $fields );
```

This will select the first form on the page that contains all the fields in `$fields` and submit the page. This way you don't have to know the form name or number or the name of the button.

You haven't posted the full HTML of the form so I'm not sure if this is relevant, but you should also know that [WWW::Mechanize does not support JavaScript](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod#I_have_this_web_page_that_has_JavaScript_on_it,_and_my_Mech_program_doesn%27t_work.). This is a common source of issues.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I didn't understand that I need first figure out the form name.
Form name was written in html I tryed to parse.

After fixing:

```
$mech->form_name('Right form name');
```

This line worked for me:

```
$mech -> click('sgnBt');
```

Thanks to all